# C++ custom iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have been trying to implement a custom forward iterator for a simple class. This class is a -pretty bad- abstraction for a fixed-array (I cannot change it unfortunately). Elements can be accessed only with an index.

```
template <class T>
struct data
{
    static const size_t MAX_BUFFER{ 50 };
    T* buffer_[MAX_BUFFER] = {};
    int currpos_ = 0;

    void insert(T *value) {
        if (currpos_ < MAX_BUFFER-1)
            buffer_[currpos_++] = value;
    }

    T** at(int i) {
        if (i >= currpos_)
            return NULL;
        return &buffer_[i];
    }

    ~data() {
        for (int i=0; i<currpos_; ++i)
            delete buffer_[i];
    }

    int entries() const { return currpos_; }

    struct iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T*>
    {
        using reference = typename std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T*>::reference;
        using pointer = typename std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T*>::pointer;

        iterator(data<T> *d, int start) : p{ d }, index{ start } {}
        iterator operator++() { if (index < p->entries()) ++index; return *this; }
        friend bool operator==(const iterator &d1, const iterator &d2) { return d1.p == d2.p && d1.index == d2.index; }
        friend bool operator!=(const iterator &d1, const iterator &d2) { return !(d1== d2); }
        reference operator*() { return *(p->at(index)); }
        pointer operator->() { return p->at(index); }
        data<T> *p;
        int index;
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(this, 0); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(this, entries()); }
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that with this interface I can use most of STL standard algorithms like for_each, transform, find_if. So for example, assuming d has been already initialized with new{2}, new{3}, new{4}, new{14}, new{-4}, new{-44}, new{42} this code

```
for (auto &i : d) std::cout <<*i <<" "; std::cout <<std::endl;

auto res=std::find_if(d.begin(), d.end(), [](auto &i) { return *i == -44;});
if (res != d.end())
    std::cout <<**res <<std::endl;

std::transform(d.begin(), d.end(), d.begin(), [](auto &i) {*i *= 2; return i;});
for (auto &i : d) std::cout <<*i <<" "; std::cout <<std::endl;
```

will correctly show

```
2 3 4 14 -4 -44 42
-44
4 6 8 28 -8 -88 84
```

The problem I'm facing is with the algorithm std::remove_if() and the way it arranges elements. I have added a member function similar to vector::erase:

```
void remove_range(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    size_t d=std::distance(begin, end);
    currpos_ -= d;
}
```

which of course should also remove the memory associated to the deleted elements. When calling it like in this example:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(d.begin(), d.end(), [](auto &r) { return *r > 3; });
d.remove_range(new_end, d.end());
```

valdring keeps telling me that I have 3 memory leaks (it makes sense: there are 3 elements >= 3). I have tried to add a delete operation into remove_range() however this solution doesn't work (the program crashes). During a debug session I printed out the internal state of d:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = {static MAX_BUFFER = <optimized out>, buffer_ = {0x603010, 0x603030, 0x603050, 0x603070, 0x603090, 0x6030b0, 0x6030d0, 0x0 <repeats 43 times>}, currpos_ = 7}
(gdb) p d
$2 = {static MAX_BUFFER = <optimized out>, buffer_ = {0x603010, 0x603030, 0x603090, 0x6030b0, 0x603090, 0x6030b0, 0x6030d0, 0x0 <repeats 43 times>}, currpos_ = 7}
```

I can see that removed_if() basically moved three elements (the ones > 3) and I think the reason I have leaks is because elements -that should be erased- are moved so the original pointers are leaked forever.

My question is: is there any way to avoid this leak here? Do I need to define some additional move constructor?

Comment: can you provide a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the problem in as few lines of code as possible? It's difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: I suggest not touching this class. If you must have it, write conversion functions to and from std::vector and only use this class as an argument to one of these functions and only when absolutely necessary. This can save you a non-trivial amount of trouble.

Comment: Could you use `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointer (`unique_ptr<T> buffer_[MAX_BUFFER];`) ?

Comment: That would be probably the best possible solution. Unfortunately that code over there is legacy code and cannot be changed :(

Answer (score 0):

The leak you see is caused by `remove_range` implementation, not iterator.

> I have added a member function similar to vector::erase ...
>   which of course should also remove the memory associated to the deleted elements.

But it does not. You call `delete` on elements in container destructor but there is no `delete` for items in erase method.

Answer (score 0):

`remove_if` collects all elements that should not be removed at the beginning of the range.  to do so, it may use either swapping or moving.  As your debug output shows, it appears to use moving, which appears to be the same as copying (which makes sense for simple data structures such as pointers).  Your debugger output shows this: the pointer 0x603090 appears twice the second time you print.  So when you call `remove_range` after `remove_if` (and have `remove_range` modified to actually call delete), you call delete on pointer values that you already copied to the front, and you will probably call delete on them a second time later, when you free the front part of the range.

On the other hand, some of the removed pointer values are truly lost, so you are unable to call delete on them, leading to memory leaks in valgrind.

The easiest fix is probably to use [`partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) instead of `remove_if`.

**EDIT:** `remove_if` is stable, `partition` isn't, so that might be a problem.  There is also `stable_partition`, but that needs bidirectional iterators, forward iterators are not enough.  Maybe you can change your iterators such that they are bidirectional?

Comment: That's exactly the same kind of solution I found. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found an answer that, at least to me, makes sense.
This is taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove and shows a possible implementation for std::remove_if.

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt remove(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    first = std::find(first, last, value);
    if (first != last)
        for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; )
            if (!(*i == value))
                *first++ = std::move(*i);
    return first;
}
```

The reason why I have a leak in my code is because of

```
*first++ = std::move(*i).
```

The only solutions I found to my problems are

1. Use a version of std::remove_if() that deletes elements before calling std::move(). In my example I just need to change

   ```
   auto new_end = std::remove_if(d.begin(), d.end(), [](auto &r) { return (*r > 3); });
   ```

into (with the same remove_range implementation)

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(d.begin(), d.end(), 
    [](auto &r) { 
        bool res = (*r > 3); 
        if (res) delete r; 
        return res; });
```

2. Use std::partition() and call manually delete for each element of the range that needs to be deleted (std::partition uses std::swap)

I recreated exactly the same problem with std::vector:

```
std::vector<int*> v{new int{1}, new int{3}, new int{-10}, new int{12}};
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &p) { return *p > 3;}));
for (auto &i : v)
    delete i;
```